# How do I create Many-to-Many relations with custom field names in Bookshelf.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js

I want to create a many-to-many relation in Bookshelf.js and want to specify the names for the FK-columns myself. I also want to be able to access the helper-table in Bookshelf as well, similar to this:

```
var Doctor = bookshelf.Model.extend({

  patients: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany(Patient).through(Appointment);
  }

});

var Appointment = bookshelf.Model.extend({

  patient: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(Patient);
  },

  doctor: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(Doctor);
  }

});

var Patient = bookshelf.Model.extend({

  doctors: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany(Doctor).through(Appointment);
  }

});
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the above example into account, one would do it this way:

```
var Doctor = bookshelf.Model.extend({

  tableName: "d_doctor",
  idAttribute: "d_doctorid",

  patients: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany(Patient).through(Appointment,"a_d_doctorid","a_p_patientid");
  }

});

var Appointment = bookshelf.Model.extend({

  tableName : "a_appointment",
  idAttribute : "a_appointmentid",

  patient: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(Patient,"a_p_patientid");
  },

  doctor: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(Doctor,"a_d_doctorid");
  }

});

var Patient = bookshelf.Model.extend({

  tableName : "p_patient",
  idAttribute : "p_patientid",

  doctors: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany(Doctor).through(Appointment,"a_p_patientid", "a_d_doctorid");
  }

});
```